# Create a table indexed form a list giving a the index specifications

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to create a table indexed form a list. e.g.:

```
list={{i, 3}, {j, 4}};
```

would give the table

```
Table[..., {i,3}, {j,4}];
```

Of course I need this because I have to create some complicated table inside a function where I do not know the number of indices i, j, k, ..., but I have a list of that with their extrema. How can I achieve this?

#### Edit

I know I have been a bit obscure, I'm only trying to write a function generating all possible [plane partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition) of a given number. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to do? It would be useful if you could show a sample input and output.

Comment: `Table[{i, j} , Evaluate[## & @@ list]]`?

Comment: Have you seen the [MathWorld notebook](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html)?

Comment: @J.M. I saw that nb but I didn't understand how to get that table just after the graph... I get an error like: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been \
superseded by preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded \
may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for \
details.

Comment: So that you don't need to load Combinatorica, replace `Partitions[]` with `IntegerPartitions[]` in the included code. I am working on improving the algorithm, so if you don't mind waiting a little...

Comment: Table[something,Evaluate[Sequence@@t]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A not-that-fast solution could be easily written:

```
f[dat_, part_] := 
  Outer[SortBy[#, -# &] & /@ Internal`PartitionRagged[##] &, 
   Permutations@dat, part, 1, 1];
PlanePartitions[n_] := 
 Module[{pt = IntegerPartitions@n, inp}, 
  inp = {#, IntegerPartitions@Length@#} & /@ pt; 
  Select[Flatten[f @@@ inp, 2], 
   With[{t = PadRight[#, {n, n}]}, 
     SortBy[#, -# &] & /@ Transpose@t == Transpose@t] &]]
```

It will partition the number, then choose multiple split method, create results and select what we want~

But efficiency is the great drawback of this method. Time sequence is shown below, and as you can see, when the number gets big, the running time canget quite nasty.

```
{0.000275014, 0.000390956, 0.000966028, 0.00265924, 0.00912323,
0.0196355, 0.0552106, 0.15279, 0.449698, 1.15818, 3.15831, 8.46536,
26.8032}
```

If I find a better solution, I'll update~

Hope this can help you~

Comment: The time consumed is about 2.5 times longer when n is increased by 1.

Comment: Also you can plot them using ArrayPlot/@PlanePartitions@9